# HTML image tag with base64 string (data URI)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, jpeg, data-uri

I get binary data of jpeg images from a series of httprequests about every 50-200 ms, I convert this data to a base64 string and insert the string in the img tag with javascript.

```
var img = document.getElementById('img1');
img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + b64str + '';
```

So when receiving greater pics, I experience that the image (first displayed fully) after some seconds get cut down from the bottom more and more until it reaches a certain point.

I searched a bit and found

> Internet Explorer 8 limits data URIs to a maximum length of 32 KB. (Internet Explorer 9 does not have this limitation)

I have no computer with IE9 to try, I only have IE8 and IE6. Could the 32kb restriction be the problem? But why does the image show up correctly the first time and after receiving the image more often it gets cut down (always form bottom up)?

Comment: Would it be possible to set the `img.src` to the same URL as the httprequest, so that it got the data directly?

Comment: Well, yes, images usually are. That doesn't answer my question. Why can't you ditch the entire `XmlHttpRequest` thing and just set the image `src` to the URL which gives you the binary image data?

Comment: because of synchronizing issues

Comment: Those being? You can use JS to change the `src` every 50ms and force a re-download of the image. If you're worried about the caching, then add a unique dummy parameter to the end of the URL each time you change it.

Comment: Well i already tried, even with the img.onload() event, the picture was always to late displayed.

Comment: If you need that kind of real-time display, then I think that you're going the wrong way entirely. What you need is streaming video. Javascript with 200 HTTP requests per second is not the right tool for the job; the performance will never be adequate.

Comment: I agree, but the situation is unchangeable for me.

Comment: What can you affect? Is the server side unchangeable, or the client side technologies? If it's the client side, then you're screwed. It won't get any faster. `XmlHttpRequest` and data URL's won't help it.

Comment: I can only tell the server to send me instead binary data, an already parsed base64 string. But the same thing happened.

Comment: Can you do something more elaborate too? One silly idea that I had was to make the server generate all the frames continuously, as frames in an animated GIF file. The browser would display them as it would receive them. The HTTP connection would never get closed, until the window was closed. It's like a poor-man's video stream.

Comment: There's just one problem - the browser would keep all the GIF data in memory. If the window stays open for a long time, that would use up a lot of RAM. A possible solution is to use Javascript which creates a new image every once in a while, and discards the old one. Though I'm not sure if the browser would cut the HTTP connection, or if this could be made seemless to the user.

Comment: Anyways, I seriously advise you to tell your employer that it cannot be (sanely) done in this manner, and a video streaming solution is needed.

Comment: Then the trick with changing the `src` should also work. It shouldn't be any slower than downloading the same data with `XmlHttpRequest`, base64-encoding it, and assigning it via a data-URL.

Comment: i am afraid not, images (sizes up to 1600x1200) will take about 3-5 seconds to be loaded (which already is to slow), and the hardware also affects the delay so its never possible to make it synchronous

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "synchronous"? Can you maybe explain more about your problem in general?

Comment: Ok, in the httprequest is a jpeg picture, and in the header is some data. With the data i construct an overly that i lay over the image. So the overlay has to be in sync with the picture when displayed on screen.

Comment: OK, **NOW** this gets weird... Please, tell me the problem in its entirety - what is that for a project, what are those for images, why are you attempting something like this, etc. Because right now this sounds plain crazy. :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say this, but for animations like this (5-20fps; realtime), Javascript and a HTTP-request-per-frame is not the right solution. You need video streaming. Otherwise, try as you might, the video will be out of sync, and the server will be overloaded with only a few people using it.

Comment: well the delay between received pictures can be slowed down to around 250ms