# how to display photo from active directory in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, active-directory, photos

how to display photo from active directory in classic asp?
I can log on to our AD and query user name telephone ect from a calssic asp page. the thumbnail photo field just returns a string, how do I format that to diaplay photo in classic asp please?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would get the image file in binary using `FileSystemObject` and use `response.contenttype = "image/jpeg"` when you return the data of the image so it renders the content as an image.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have a work around ( below) which loads the picture into a page within an iframe. Page 1 calls this with the user name to query as a querystring ( req below). The XXX should be replaced with a username and password that has permissions to read all users data in AD. My only problem now is that the image shows with a white border in IE. <% strUsername = request.querystring("req") Set objDomain = GetObject ("GC://rootDSE") objADsPath = objDomain.Get("defaultNamingContext")
'### Continued..

Comment: Set objDomain = Nothing
Set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.provider ="ADsDSOObject"
con.Properties("User ID") = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
con.Properties("Password") = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
con.Properties("Encrypt Password") = False
con.open "Active Directory Provider"
Set Com = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set Com.ActiveConnection = con
Com.CommandText ="select thumbnailPhoto FROM 'GC://"+objADsPath+"' where sAMAccountname='"+strUsername+"'"

Set rs = Com.Execute
Response.Expires = 0  ntin
Response.Buffer = TRUE  
Response.Clear

Comment: Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg" 
'#### Assuming your images are jpegs 
if not rs.eof then
Response.BinaryWrite rs("thumbnailPhoto")  
else 
   response.write "image for " &  strUsername & " Not found"
end if
rs.Close
con.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set con = Nothing
%>

Comment: An improvement:
Replace the iframe with
<img src="getaduserimage.asp?req=FIRSTNAME.SURNAME" width="100" height="100" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" />

Answer (score 0):

You can also render the photo inline in an image:

...img src=[base64 presentation of the image]>...

[HTML image tag with base64 string (data URI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134707/html-image-tag-with-base64-string-data-uri-scheme)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using html img tag. for example:

```
<img src="<%=myPhotoUrl%>">
```

In asp code block, you must declare it as:

```
<%
    Response.Write "<img src=""" & myPhotoUrl & """>"
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the answer I have come up with that works is:
    strUsername = request.querystring("req")
    strUserRole = request.querystring("rol")

```
Set objDomain = GetObject ("GC://rootDSE")
objADsPath = objDomain.Get("defaultNamingContext")
Set objDomain = Nothing
Set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.provider ="ADsDSOObject"
con.Properties("User ID") = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
con.Properties("Password") = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
con.Properties("Encrypt Password") = False
con.open "Active Directory Provider"
Set Com = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set Com.ActiveConnection = con
Com.CommandText ="select name,telephonenumber,mail,thumbnailPhoto, Department, title FROM 'GC://"+objADsPath+"' where sAMAccountname='"+strUsername+"'"

Set rs = Com.Execute
if not rs.eof then
 tmpphoto=rs("thumbnailPhoto")
 tmpdept=rs("Department")
 tmptitle=rs("title") 
 name=rs("name")
 telephonenumber=rs("telephonenumber")
 mail=rs("mail") 
 NameArr = Split(name, " ")
 cname = NameArr(0)
 sname = NameArr(1)
rs.Close
con.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set con = Nothing

 %>
 <div id="card"><img src="badge.jpg"  width="100%"/>
<div id="personname"><%=cname & " " & sname%></div>
<div id="persongroup"><%=tmptitle%></div>
<div id="persondept"><%=tmpdept%></div>
<div id="personrole"><%=strUserRole%></div>
<div id="personimage">  
    <img src="getaduserimage.asp?req=NAME.SURNAME" width="100" height="100" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" />

</div>
<div id="logoimage"><img src="OUR_logo_white_small.png"  width="100"/></div>
<%
 else 
   cname = strUsername & " Not found"
end if


%>

<% 'getaduserimage.asp file contains:
strUsername = request.querystring("req")
Set objDomain = GetObject ("GC://rootDSE")
objADsPath = objDomain.Get("defaultNamingContext")
Set objDomain = Nothing
Set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.provider ="ADsDSOObject"
con.Properties("User ID") = "xxxxxx"
con.Properties("Password") = "xxxxxxxx"
con.Properties("Encrypt Password") = False
con.open "Active Directory Provider"
Set Com = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set Com.ActiveConnection = con
Com.CommandText ="select thumbnailPhoto FROM 'GC://"+objADsPath+"' where sAMAccountname='"+strUsername+"'"

Set rs = Com.Execute
Response.Expires = 0  
Response.Buffer = TRUE  
Response.Clear  
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg" 
'#### Assuming your images are jpegs 
if not rs.eof then
Response.BinaryWrite rs("thumbnailPhoto")  
else 
   response.write "image for " &  strUsername & " Not found"
end if
rs.Close
con.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set con = Nothing
%>
```